# XAML Files are not loading and showing as catastrophic Failure in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xaml

I don't know what's happene but i couldn't solve it !!! I've tryied delete the `.vs` folder and the `ComponentModelCache` folder but no one of them work I even try to reset and reinstall the visual studio but the problem still !!!!
I've got this message everytime I click on the xaml design

[image]

I hope anyone can help me !!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Right click on the .xaml file and then choose open with. Then choose the first option that appears, it should be "Automatic Editor Selected (XML)". Click ok and then it should start working again.

Comment: I have tried what you are suggested but I am getting 'Visual studio encountered has an unexpected error.' popup.